# Defining a new operation (From the International Mathematical Tournament of the Towns)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

An operation denoted by * defines, for each pair of numbers (x, y), a number x * y such that for all x, y and z the following identities hold:

x * x = 0;
x * (y * z) = (x * y) + z

Where + denotes ordinary addition of numbers. Find 1993 * 1932

My plan of action was to first see if I can get some identities involving 1 and 0 going. Try to see if I can isolate some kind of definition of x * y in terms of normal operations. I am unable to move beyond this point. Hint Please!

Comment: What is ox?  What is o? What is "concatenation"?

Comment: Hint: what happens if $x=y=z$ in the second identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two rules:

1. $x * x = 0$
2. $x * (y * z) = (x * y) + z$

Consider rule 2 under the substitution $y: = x$, $z := x$. We have $x * (x * x) = (x * x) + x$, and by applying rule 1 on each side we get rule 3:

3. $x * 0 = x$

Now consider rule 2 under the substitution $z := y$.